# Opposite of tenancy?

Tags: single-word-requests

As a tenant, one might say to their landlord

> It has been a pleasure staying under your ____

What word might fit here?

Comment: .......... roof?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth feels strange when the tenant and landlord have not been living in the same (or attached) property.

Comment: _auspices_ maybe?

Comment: Or maybe _shade_ if the person was sorta protective, caring, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The opposite of ***tenancy*** would be ***landlordship***:

> the condition or position of a landlord ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landlordship#:%7E:text=%3A%20the%20condition%20or%20position%20of%20a%20landlord))

Consider:

> In 1415, Langenthal became incorporated into the territory of the Republic of Bern, but it remained ***under the landlordship*** and the low court of the monastery. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langenthal))

So your sentence would like this

> It has been a pleasure staying under your landlordship.

However, I must say, this would be a rather uncommon statement. I would simply say:

> It has been a pleasure ***being your tenant***.

That does not mean, however, that you will find ***no*** instance of ***under your landlordship***. Here's the proof:

> It would also be beneficial for your rental business to get many good tenants ***under your landlordship***. ([Realtytoday](https://www.realtytoday.com/articles/74597/20160120/attracting-good-tenant-proactive-property-changes-2016-needed.htm))

Comment: Or, following your rephrasing: It has been a pleasure doing business with you.

Comment: Yes, true, although your rephrasing is more general and includes more aspects than the mere tenant-landlord relationship.

Comment: Hmm... If you **do** use *landlordship* when speaking to your landlord, remember to genuflect appropriately.